# Access Windows FileShare for all users in EC2 instance setup using userdata

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer, user-data

We have an EC2 instance with a Files Share. Until now we could access it via UNC like so `\\files.server.com`.

Now we've started using packer and Ansible to setup our servers in deployment. After `sysprep` all the credentials get deleted and we need to create the access once again using the UserData script.

One more thing we need to give this access to all of our users because we have special user for our Windows service.

I have tried many things and still no luck, from `New-PSDrive`, `NET USE`,`MapNetworkDrive`, CredentialsManager and so on.

I would appreciate some assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but I use the `commands:` section of a `configSet` within CloudFormation:

```
  commands:

    10-Create-Local-Fileshare-Directory:
      command: >-
        powershell.exe -Command New-Item "D:\Shared" -type directory
      waitAfterCompletion: '0'
    11-Create-Fileshare:
      command: >-
        powershell.exe -Command New-SmbShare -Name my-fileshare -Path "D:\Shared"
      waitAfterCompletion: '0'
    12-Grant-Fileshare-Permissions:
      command: >-
        powershell.exe -Command Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name my-fileshare -AccountName Everyone -AccessRight Change -Force
      waitAfterCompletion: '0'
```

You could do the same if you're using CloudFormation or just pull out the Powershell commands you need.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Yet this creates the file share on the local computer, isn't it? I need to get access to the file share that is already exist.

Comment: So, you just need to grant all-access permissions to the existing fileshare? Won't the`Grant-SmbShareAccess` command do that for you?